# jquery datatable : fetch next 25 rows from databse on next page button of jQuery datatable

Tags: jquery, mysql, angular, datatables

I have huge number of data that I want to populate in jQuery datatable. I am using mysql database. Is it possible in angularJs to use jQuery datatable in such way that on first time only 25 records will be extracted and shown in datatable. On next or 2 button click next 25 records will be extracted and shown.

Below is my code for datatable in angular controller.

```
     $($scope.getDataPointDetails = function () {

         dataPointFactory.getDataPointDetails().then(
             function (response) {
                 for (var i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++)
                 {
                     dataPointData[i] = new Array(
                         '<i class="material-icons waves-effect" onclick="editDataPoint('+ i +');" data-toggle = "tooltip" data-placement = "left" title = "Edit">edit</i> \n\
                          <i class="material-icons waves-effect" onclick="DeleteDataPoint('+ i +');" data-toggle = "tooltip" data-placement = "left" title = "Delete">delete</i>',                          
                         response.data[i].companyName, //1
                         (response.data[i].addressLine1+', '+((response.data[i].addressLine1!==null)?response.data[i].addressLine1:'')+', '+response.data[i].city+'-'+response.data[i].pinCode), //2
                         response.data[i].state, //3
                         response.data[i].contactNos, //4
                         response.data[i].tollFreeNo, //5
                         response.data[i].compEmail, // 6
                         response.data[i].compWebsite, //7
                         response.data[i].level1, //8
                         response.data[i].level2, //9
                         response.data[i].level3, //10
                         response.data[i].remark1, //11
                         response.data[i].remark2, //12
                         response.data[i].remark3, //13 
                         response.data[i].ptc1, //14
                         response.data[i].ptc2, //15
                         response.data[i].ptc3, //16
                         response.data[i].ptc4, //17
                         response.data[i].ptc5, //18
                         response.data[i].tallySrNo, //19
                         response.data[i].tallyProdType, //20
                         response.data[i].noOfUsers, //21
                         response.data[i].tallyDuration, //22
                         response.data[i].tallyStartDate, //23
                         response.data[i].tallyEndDate, //24
                         response.data[i].drn,//25
                         response.data[i].addressLine1,//26
                         response.data[i].addressLine2, //27
                         response.data[i].city, //28
                         response.data[i].pincode //29
                         );
                 }

                 $('#dataPointViewTable').dataTable({
                     "destroy": true,
                     "aaSorting": [],
                     "deferRender": true,
                     "responsive": true,
                     "aaData": dataPointData,
                     "bAutoWidth": false,
//                     "fixedColumns":   {
//                         leftColumns: 1,
//                         rightColumns: 1
//                     },
                     "processing": true,
                     "serverSide": true,
                     "aoColumns": [
                         {"sTitle": "Action", "sWidth": "5%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Company Name", "sWidth": "5%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Address", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "State", "sWidth": "8%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Contact Number", "sWidth": "10%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Toll Free Number", "sWidth": "10%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Email Address", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Website", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Level1", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Level2", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Level3", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Remark1", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Remark2", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Remark3", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Contact Person 1(Name, Designation, Email, Mobile No.)", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Contact Person 2(Name, Designation, Email, Mobile No.)", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Contact Person 3(Name, Designation, Email, Mobile No.)", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Contact Person 4(Name, Designation, Email, Mobile No.)", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Contact Person 5(Name, Designation, Email, Mobile No.)", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Tally Serial No", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Product Type", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "No of Users", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "Duration", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "TSS Purshase Date", "sWidth": "15%"},
                         {"sTitle": "TSS Expiry Date", "sWidth": "15%"}]
                 });

             });
     });
```

I have added server side processing options to data table. I am getting response for $http which I am able to see in network but not in table and I am getting popup alert message for datatable as-
DataTables warning: table id=dataPointViewTable - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: show your code.

Answer (score 0):

Enable [server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/data/#Server-side-processing) using [`serverSide`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/serverSide) option.

Write your own server-side script that will handle sorting, filtering and pagination on the server side. DataTables comes with `ssp.class.php` that helps with that if your language of choise is PHP.